# Providing website in only html 5?

Tags: html

I am designing a website which has to reach old and new browsers. With this in mind should I program in HTML5? Currently the website is only in html 5. The question is: **Is it stupid in my case to use HTML5, should I use a "switch"(is this even possible) to redirect old browsers?**

Comment: There are a lot of, let says tools, that supports html5 and in case they just fallback in html4 with minor changes. It depends what you mean only html5, a web site cannot be only html5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, what aspects of html5 do you plan to use?

If your website is mostly static html & javascript, no audio and no embedded video, then I would say it use HTML4.

If your not using any tags in html5 dont rush it, no

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to reach a broad audience, I wouldn't necessarily jump into HTML 5 yet.  It's still not supported widely or consistently enough to rely on it.  However, there are several resources available if you want to give it a shot.

[When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/) should be a big help.  It shows which features of HTML 5 are supported in which browsers fairly clearly.  It would probably be good to research further about each tag you plan on using.  Learn how the major browsers have implemented the tags, and if there's any quirks or bare-bones implementations that might be an obstacle to the average user.

I've heard [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) listed as a means of leveraging HTML 5 elements while maintaining backwards support for old browsers.  Do note that I can't testify personally to how well it performs, having never used it before.